# SAS calculating new variable for a new dataset from an existing Dataset

Tags: variables, sas, creation

This is a portion of given dataset, `projet.details_etest`:

```
 "survey_instance_id"  "user_id"   "question_id"    "Item_correct"
'"2008"                "14389"        "4243"           "0"
'"2008"                "14489"        "4243"           "1"
'"2008"                "14499"        "4253"           "0"
'"2008"                "1669"         "4253"           "1"
```

I want to create a new dataset called `projet.resume_question` which contains the dataset details sort by `question_id`, containing the variables:

- `survey_instance_id`
- `question_id`
- `nb_correct_answers`
- `nb_incorrect answers`
- `nb_omitted_answers`
- `nb_total_with_omitted_answers`
- `nb_total_without_omitted_answers`

The variable `nb_omitted_answers` is the total number of participants minus `nb_correct_answers`, the number of correct answers per question, minus `nb_incorrect_answers`, the number of incorrect answers per question.

The variable `nb_total_with_omitted_answers` is the total number of participants who have participated in the test.

The variable `nb_total_without_omitted_answers` is the total number of participants who have answered each question.

Here is what I did:

```
   data projet.resume_question;
set projet.details_etest;
by question_id;
keep survey_instance_id question_id nb_correct_answers nb_incorrect_answers;
retain nb_correct_answers 0 nb_incorrect_answers 0;
if Item_correct =1 then correct_answers= Item_correct;
else if Item_correct =0 then incorrect_answers= Item_correct;
nb_correct_answers = sum (correct_answers);
nb_incorrect_answers= sum (incorrect_answers);
run;
proc print data=projet.resume_question;
run;
```

I start this way and what I found seems wrong to me when I printed it. Can someone help me please?

Comment: I think you need to give an example of the expected final dataset to make this question make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First sort the dataset by survey, question, participant.

```
proc sort data = projet.details_etest out = details;
    by survey_instance_id question_id user_id;
run;
```

Now get the number of participants for each survey.

```
proc sql;
    create table participated as
    select survey_instance_id,
        count(distinct user_id) as nb_total_with_omitted_answers
    from details
    group by survey_instance_id;
quit;
```

Compute the aggregates by survey, question.

```
data aggregated;
    set details;
    by survey_instance_id question_id;

    retain nb_total_without_omitted_answers
           nb_correct_answers nb_incorrect_answers 0;

    if first.question_id then do;
        nb_total_without_omitted_answers = 0;
        nb_correct_answers = 0;
        nb_incorrect_answers = 0;
    end;

    if item_correct in (0, 1) then nb_total_without_omitted_answers + 1;

    if item_correct = 1 then nb_correct_answers + 1;
    else if item_correct = 0 then nb_incorrect_answers + 1;

    if last.question_id then output;

    drop user_id item_correct;
run;
```

Lastly, compute the number of omitted answers per question.

```
data projet.resume_question;
    merge participated aggregated;
    by survey_instance_id;

    nb_omitted_answers = nb_total_with_omitted_answers -
        nb_correct_answers - nb_incorrect_answers;
run;
```

This should get you what you need.